# How would i make a gameobject randomly choose from points and teleport to one of them?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am making a FNAF fangame, and i want the "animatronic" to choose between points to move to and go to them on a timer(and keep doing it not just doing it once), how would i go about doing this?

Comment: So what is your question? "How to do something repeatedly in certain time intervals?" .. or "How to pick a random element from a list?" .. or "How to move objects?" .. I'm pretty sure that for each of these you will already find questions and answers here on StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a float as a time value, every Update add Time.deltaTime to it. When it gets greater than a set amount of seconds, set it to zero and call a method that places the animatronic.private

```
   float time=0;
   public float delay=10;

   public void Update()
   {
   time+=Time.deltaTime;
   if(time>=delay)
   {
   Place();
   }

   }

   private void Place()
   {
   //place the animatronic
   //choose the location wuth Random.Range(float,float)
   }
```